# ignore hidden empty textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox

Quick update, i found out why the code wont work, all the textboxes i want to check are in groupboxes and thats the problem, if i remove the groupbox the problem is resolved. 
Is there a way around this ?

Found the solution.
Posted below for future reference.

Thanks again for all your imput.

```
        foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))
    {
        if (textBox is TextBox && textBox.Visible && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Missing {textBox.Name} value!");
            Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for `if (larg.Visible == true)` **Note the non capitalised boolean value**. I am not sure hidden is a property of textBoxes, if it is then your line should read `if (larg.Hidden == false)` The issue is that a bool cannot be capitalised, as that is not the value - it is easier to help if you tell us the error

Comment: Do I get you correctly - your code works but you just get and error in the * if (larg.Hidden == False)* codeline? You get an Compiler error? I guess you get an runtime error. 
Is this wpf or winforms ? You call it "form" so I guess it's winforms, right?

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre the code works but now i click next and nothing happens.

Comment: @MarcIT in that case you have your bools the wrong way round now, change the `true` to `false` (or vice versa)

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre i tried already, if i change to true i get the messages but i get them even for the hidden textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using a foreach of the form's controls instead? Something like:

```
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && c.Visible && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"TextBox {c.Name} is empty");
            }
        }
```

EDIT: If your form contains groupboxes, groupboxes are groups of controls so you will have to iterate through their controls with a sub-foreach too. Here's how:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckControlCollection(this.Controls);
    }
    private void CheckControlCollection(Control.ControlCollection cc)
    {
        foreach (Control c in cc)
            if (c is GroupBox)
                CheckControlCollection(c.Controls);
            else
                CheckControl(c);
    }
    private void CheckControl(Control c)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c.Visible && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            MessageBox.Show($"TextBox {c.Name} is empty");
    }
```

This will make sure we don't get screwed by nested groupboxes

Comment: The code works but i dont get a message when nothing is written in the textbox.the app crashes

Comment: @MarcIT what are **larg* and **alt**? from your code I assume they are textboxes, if so, why are you checking their visibility status instead the current loop iteration's visibility, while checking every textbox in the form?

Comment: yes they are textboxes. can you give me an exampe please?

Comment: So if i understand correctly your code shoul check all textboxes at once?
I tried to apply it but still get the error when textbox is empty

Comment: **Controls** returns a collection of all the controls in your Form. with **foreach** we iterate through each item in that collection where the variable **c** will represent a single element. In my example I inserted a condition where I checked if **c** was a **TextBox** (to filter the possible control types). In addition, whether **c** was **Visible** and if its **Text** property was an empty string. You changed **c.Visible** to **larg.Visible**,  so that for each TextBox element in the form it will not check if that specific checkbox is visible, it will check if larg is visible instead.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  it makes sense now. but for some reason the error keeps happening

Comment: @MarcIT sadly I can't tell what the error is/could be from the amount of information you have provided

Comment: well i tried everything i could think of, even place the code in other places, but nothing. the code should be placed right after `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` right?

Comment: @MarcIT depends, I am not aware of how your application is structured, nor what clicking button1 does. like i said, without seeing the entire thing I can't really tell

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you but is there a way i can show you the code from this form so that you can diagnose the problem? i´ve been trying and cant figure out what the problem is. i even tested de code on a new app and it works perfectly. Thanks for the support

Comment: @MarcIT you can zip and upload the code or even the whole project to whichever site and share the link and I'll give it a look when I can

Comment: thanks for the help, you can get the code here. : [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1426214729e15fefa610cb2257bec02d20161121123717/4a95a8) i removed some code to facilitate interpretation. your code is in line 154

Comment: I finally found out what the problem is. all the textboxes are in groupboxes and wont get found like this. is there a way aroud the problem? or will i have to remove the groupboxes?

Comment: @MarcIT Yea, I expected something like that, I can't check your uploaded file from the workplace network but I've updated my answer

Comment: now i have another problem, is there a way to ignore certain textboxes, not all of them are mandatory. :\

Comment: @MarcIT depends, you have many properties to your disposal, you'll have to be more specific. Another simple way is to give non mandatory textboxes a certain name format, which you can retrieve and filter while iteration trhough the controls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128631/discussion-between-innat3-and-marcit).